# how to save xsl file in client pc if i am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: asp.net

when i am working in my personal pc ,my below code working fine and xsl is going to save in specified path.
but when application is hosted and  during saving of xsl file, i am getting error message like
 **Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC**

please let me know how to save xsl file in client pc .i need to modify my code.???

```
  public void Convertoxsl(DataSet ds)
        {
            Application ExcelApp = new Application();
            Workbook ExcelWorkBook = null;
            Worksheet ExcelWorkSheet = null;
            string FileName = string.Empty;
            ExcelApp.Visible = true;
            ExcelWorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);

            List<string> SheetNames = new List<string>();
            string sn = ddlPageName.SelectedItem.Text;
            SheetNames.Add(sn);


            try
            {
                int getcol = 0;
                for (int i = 1; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
                    ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets.Add(); //Adding New sheet in Excel Workbook

                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
                {
                    int r = 1; // Initialize Excel Row Start Position  = 1

                    ExcelWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets[i + 1];

                    //Writing Columns Name in Excel Sheet

                    for (int col = 1; col <= ds.Tables[i].Columns.Count; col++)
                    {
                        if (ds.Tables[i].Columns.Count != 3)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, col] = ds.Tables[i].Columns[col - 1].ColumnName;
                        getcol = col;
                    }



                       r++;



                    //Writing Rows into Excel Sheet
                    for (int row = 0; row < ds.Tables[i].Rows.Count; row++) //r stands for ExcelRow and col for ExcelColumn
                    {
                        // Excel row and column start positions for writing Row=1 and Col=1
                        for (int col = 1; col <= ds.Tables[i].Columns.Count; col++)
                            ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[r, col] = ds.Tables[i].Rows[row][col - 1].ToString();


                        r++;
                    }
 ExcelWorkSheet.Name = SheetNames[i];//Renaming the ExcelSheets


            }


           string dirPageName = D:\projectPath;
           FileName =dirPageName +abc + ".xlsx";


            if (!Directory.Exists(dirPageName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPageName);
            }

            if (File.Exists(FileName))
            {
                File.Delete(FileName);
            }


            ExcelWorkBook.SaveAs(FileName);

            ExcelWorkBook.Close();
            ExcelApp.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelWorkSheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelWorkBook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelApp);
            ltMessage.Text ="File Successfully exported";
            ltMessage.Visible = true;




        }
        catch (Exception exHandle)
        {



            ltMessage.Text = exHandle.Message;
            ltMessage.Visible = true;
        }
        finally
        {

            foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("Excel"))
                process.Kill();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

HRESULT: 0x800A03EC is an unknown (to VB.Net) COM error. This usually happens when Excel throws some error because your input or parameters were wrong or didn't work.

Also check the error detail carefully. In my case the Data section had an Item that gave me clues about the exact error thrown by Excel.

@Erwin says: The IIS user account has to have permissions to write the file. Search for 0x800A03EC in the following article, [How to Create Excel file in ASP.NET C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/jayendra/how-to-create-excel-file-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/)